# PHP timer output into HTML div every second

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, timer

I developed a PHP countdown timer (3hrs specifically in hrs, mins and secs) - countdown.php. The output is within a `<div>` tag in another page - index.html.

I want an AJAX or Javascript that would make the output dynamic (that is changing figures like normal timer).  I do know that AJAX can make the page refresh every second in the background (asynchronously), but I've not been able to achieve that.

Presently, the output only changes when I refresh the HTML page. I also want a PHP script to be triggered when countdown gets to zero.

#### countdown.php

```
<?php
//some codes left out    
 $remainingHour=floor($secsdiff/3600);
 $remainingMinute=floor(($secsdiff-($remainingHour*60*60))/60);
 $remainingSecond=floor(($secsdiff-($remainingHour*60*60))-($remainingMinute*60));
?>
```

#### index.html

```
<div id="timer">
<?php echo "$remainingHour hours, $remainingMinute minutes, 
$remainingSecond seconds";?>
</div>
```

Comment: O_o Why are you using PHP to display a dynamic changing value at the client's side? You can use JavaScript to count down, and use PHP 1x to supply the starting offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your using JQuery in your HTML page (Follow the tutes on the JQ website if this is new to you, It's really very easy)

Then once your up and running with that, use JQuerys Get function to update your div:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

You should be able to get it up and working in 30 mins or less, it's very simple.

Comment: It's always worked for me....   but then again, the times I've used it have all been internal portals.

Comment: thanks shawty...i used ajax and php to set the timer rolling. am about sputnick's suggestion for the redirection. am still having a hitch though..how to make the setTimeout stop when countdown gets to zero. am using responseText for my feedback and not responseXML..i've not been able to manipulate this though..i think it sees everything from responseText as a string and not integer

Answer (score 0):

If this is just a small item on a larger page, I would use Ajax or JavaScript. With Ajax you should be able to check for 0 values and if it is reached, notify that to the server, where server will perform specification action.

You probably can do that with JavaScript a s well which might be more desirable for such small tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setTimeout` function in javascript, see [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+setTimeout&submit=search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20setTimeout&submit=search)

When the timer will be over, simply call a new URL to execute the next php script (still in javascript), like :

```
document.location.href = http://foobar.tld/new_page
```

Comment: i got it all figured out. thanx. i used Ajax and PHP to create my dynamic countdown.